# I try to join two threads from the main thread, after calling wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading

Firstly, I try to define a class that contains 2 synchronized methods, the first one contains a wait() calling, and the second contains notify() calling.

```
 class Xa {
 public synchronized void printX() {
    try {
        wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("XXX");
}

public synchronized void notifyX() {
    System.out.println("111");
    notify();
}
}
```

Then I try to make two threads in the main, the first one call the printX() method of an object of the Xa class, and the second one call the notifyX() method of the same object, and finally the main thread join the two threads.

And I repeat this scenario with a for loop

```
public class TryQ {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Thread t1 = null;
    Thread t2 = null;
    for(int i=1 ; i<=100; i++) {
        Xa x = new Xa();

        t1 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                x.printX();
            }
        };

        t2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                x.notifyX();
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
}
```

The problem is, without joining, both the first and the second thread, print 100 times exactly, but when I try to join them by the main thread, I have maximum 2 or 3 lines of output... and the program is still running!

Why?

Comment: `join()` method used to waits for this thread to die, so you main thread bolcked.

Comment: It seems like whether the program completes is pretty much a matter of chance, join or not. If t2 happens to run before t1 then t1 never finishes. This is not how you use wait.

Comment: Once you do some of these puzzles to learn, take this as an example of why using `wait` and `notify` is a bad practice when much better concurrency utilities are now available.

Comment: @chrylis like what please?

Comment: `wait()` and `notify()` are low-level primitives that you can use to implement your own "better concurrency utilities" if the standard library doesn't already provide something that works for you. That shouldn't happen often though because you can do quite a lot with blocking queues, barriers, semaphores, and other goodies from the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exists whether you use `join` or not.

The problem is, if `t2` executes `notifyX` first,

```
public synchronized void notifyX() {
    System.out.println("111");
    notify();
}
```

then `t1` calls `printX`, `t1` will get block forever!

```
public synchronized void printX() {
    try {
        wait();   <--- since t2 has finished, t1 will get stuck here!
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("XXX");
}
```

The  difference is:

- without `join`, though the first `t1` is stuck, the main thread will create a  new `t1` and run.
- with `join`, since the first `t1` is stuck, the `join` will block the main thread, so there won't be next generation.

Comment: Yes exactly that is! Typical Answer